# What's the connection between force and energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, friction

I know that energy is equal to the work done and work is equal to the multiplication of force and displacement caused my the force in the direction of the applied force.
But when friction is involved, things seem to be unclear to me. Like if I apply a force $F$ on a object which causes displacement of $s$ and the friction is $F_k$. Then the object will feel a net force of $F-F_k$. So what will be the work done? Will it be

1. $W = \vec{F}.\vec{s}$,  or
2. $W= \vec{(F-F_k)}.\vec{s}$

I don't feel like the first one is correct because if we use kinetic energy to solve this problem,
Then W=0.5(Object's Mass)(Its final velocity)<sup>2</sup>

Here the velocity is the only variable and the velocity completely depends on the net force which is $(F-F_k)$.
Now this is my understanding of the problem but it is completely dependent on the definition of force which i am unsure about.
Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: *"I know that energy is equal to the work done..."* No, it's not. The net work is equal to the *change* in kinetic energy. The work done by any individual conservative force is the negative of the *change* in that individual potential energy.

Comment: Total work done should act upon net force : $W_{\Sigma} = \vec F_{\Sigma} \cdot \vec s$. And probably since it's a dot product, angle also matters, because you can push object at an angle to horizontal, hence work done will be smaller, because not your all force will be used for conversion into kinetic energy, hence : $W_{\Sigma} = |\vec F_{\Sigma}| \cdot |\vec s|~\cdot \cos(\alpha)$

Comment: meta discussion here: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14600/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the key here is all the work done did not go into the kinetic energy.

Your measure of work as total force times distance applied is correct $F\cdot s$ or option 1.

That work partly went into kinetic energy but also it went into heat due to the friction force. In fact you can use the quantity $F_k \cdot s$ to measure how much of that work ended up going into friction and $F\cdot s - F_k\cdot s$ is what actually went into the kinetic energy of the object. It should be the case that $F\cdot s = F_k\cdot s + KE$  in this model. So here $F\cdot s$ is seen clearly as the total work.

### For clarification:

Total work is not a concept I think most people work with. Most people have a concept called "net work" which is just the change in kinetic energy, and the "net force" is the force which is integrated over the distance it is applied to result in this change in kinetic energy. The fact friction occurred and some energy was lost to heat doesn't even enter the mental model here (though its certainly real and very much still there) and that can be helpful in other situations for thinking about these things.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I now know the proper definition of work.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck in your studies! I also recommend picking up a little bit of LaTeX/MathJax for asking questions :)

Answer (score 4):

When pushing an object of mass $m$ with a force of $F$ in straight line along a horizontal surface with friction between the object and the surface, two things are doing work on the object: (1)the source of the pushing force (say you) and (2) the kinetic friction force that is opposing the pushing force

The work you do moving the object a displacement $d$ is

$$W_{you}=Fd$$

The work friction does for the displacement $d$ where $\mu_k$ is the coefficient of kinetic friction and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity is

$$W_{f}=-\mu_{k}mgd$$

The friction work is negative because the friction force acts in a direction opposite to the displacement.

The net work done on the object is

$$W_{net}=W_{you}+W_{f}=Fd-\mu_{k}mgd$$

Per the work energy theorem the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy, or

$$Fd-\mu_{k}mgd=\frac{1}{2}mv_{f}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}mv_{i}^2$$

Where $v_f$ and $v_i$ are the final and initial velocities of the object, respectively.

Note that the negative work of friction takes away the kinetic energy of the  motion of the object and dissipates it as heat.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

So when one wants to calculate the work done on an object moving under force in a straight line, say along the x-axis, the relevant formula in volves the scalar or dot product of vectors:$$W=\vec F\cdot \vec s $$ We have that $\vec F=\vec F+\vec f_k=(F-f_k)\vec i$, and the displacement is $\vec s=s\vec i$ so that the *total* work done is:$$W=(F-f_k)s.$$ The work energy theorem is applicable so that one has:$${1\over 2}m(v_f^2-v_i^2)=(F-f_k)s,$$ from which relation one might calculate any one of four quantities $v_i$, $v_f$, $F$, $f_k$, or $s$ depending on which quantities are known. One can calculate the total done by $\vec F$ according to:$$W_F={1\over 2}m(v_f^2-v_i^2)+f_ks, $$or the work done by $\vec f_k$:$$W_{f_k}=Fs-{1\over s}m(v_f^2-v_i^2).$$

Answer (score 0):

Work done on a particle is not the intrinsic property of the particle itself. Different forces can have different work done on the particle. The *net* work done, i.e. the summation of work done by all forces (by friction and the force $F$ in this case), however, is equal to change in kinetic energy of the particle.